# How to repair Windows partition after moving GRUB in different disk

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I had a dual boot setup with Windows 8 and Ubuntu. The laptop has a normal HDD and a smaller SSD. Both OS were on the HDD.

I decided to make a clean install of a newer version of Ubuntu on the SSD. The Windows partition is still on the HDD.

But now I cannot boot Windows and I am not sure what I should do to fix the issue.

Here are some pics from gparted.

[HDD][image]

[SSD][image]

Comment: I normally would use the Windows Recovery console to repair the windows bootloader in a situation like this.

Comment: Yes, but how can I access the recovery console? I don't see anything related in the GRUB menu (other than the entry for Windows 8).

Comment: You can try to repair your boot grub using ubuntu live cd

Comment: Why are you trying to use Grub?  You need to boot to a Windows disk, in order to repair the Windows boot loader.  You need to fix the Windows boot loader before it will show up in grub.

Comment: Ok the problem was that I don't have the windows 8 CD for this setup (nor a CD driver for that matter). I found a solution though. F12 during boot brings up an option to select where to boot from, and I found an option in the end that started the windows repair which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I don't have the windows 8 CD for this setup (nor a CD driver for that matter). I found a solution though. F12 during boot brings up an option to select where to boot from, and I found an option in the end that started the windows repair which fixed the issue.