# After removing Ubuntu 14.04 and attempting to install Windows 8, Windows was corrupted

Tags: windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 as a dual boot. Then I downloaded Windows 8.1 and started to install it.  When the PC restarted it asked me to select an OS (Ubuntu or Windows 8)  to boot into.  I selected Windows 8 and when Windows started the Windows 8.1 installation didn't continue and my PC automatically restarted every 2 minutes.  Now I want to remove Linux and keep Windows so I tried to delete the Linux partition but it failed.  Then I did an advanced startup and, using command prompt, I entered the command :

bootrec.exe /fixmbr

After that the problem started.  Now Windows 8 doesn't start.  The Windows 8 logo appears and remains the same, nothing happens...

I tried to repair Windows using my usb by creating a bootable media of Windows 8 using RmPrep but setup didn't start and again the Windows logo appeared on the screen.

Please help me..
I'm stuck..

Comment: So it  didn't boot from the USB installer? Are you sure it's bootable? Did you set the boot order properly in the BIOS?

Comment: Why did you not perform the upgrade first?  Simplest solution replace grub with the Windows loader then once the upgrade is finished repair grub but you were to hasty and that's now not possible

Answer (score 0):

You may want to download [A Boot Repair Disc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/latest/download).

Put the image onto a DVD or USB and boot to it and run the tool.  If that doesn't work, you can boot to it again and backup anything you want to save and then download [Gparted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect) and boot to that.  Use Gparted to reformat your hard drive and then try to install windows again.

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) makes putting all of these distros/tools onto a bootable usb very easy.

When doing an update or installation of windows it often restarts multiple times.  It get very annoying and can take an incredible amount of time but manually stopping the process can cause serious problems with your operating system.  I would backup your data and start with a fresh installation, that will probably be a lot easier than trying to fix whatever is going on.

This [Windows installation media page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) should help if you don't have a windows 8 disk.

[Using GParted to convert GPT to MBR without access to an OS](https://superuser.com/questions/642420/using-gparted-to-convert-gpt-to-mbr-without-access-to-an-os)

[How to repair Windows partition after moving GRUB in different disk](https://superuser.com/questions/776086/how-to-repair-windows-partition-after-moving-grub-in-different-disk)

There's a bunch of questions to help you with all these steps.

Comment: can I repair my pc using easyRE

Comment: I don't know.  Sorry, Their web page says it will, but I have never used it.  I have used the things listed in the post though.

Comment: I tried using EasyRE , but it didn't worked but now I think that my HDD is got damaged..  :-(

Comment: Did you try any of  my suggestions at all?